# VS Code save before build task does not trigger format on save

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

Has anybody managed to successfully combine save before build and format on save in VS Code?
(i.e. running a build task both formats and saves a file before building, either from the Run menu or by pressing Ctl+Shift+B keyboard shortcut).
Is defining this behavior even possible and if so would anybody be so kind as to explain how to achieve this?

I do have both of these enabled. Format on save works on it's own, however running a build task only saves the file and format on save is not executed.

Answer (score 0):

From googling "`github vscode issues format on save before task run`", I found issue ticket [Run build task formats my file #96904](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/96904), which was implemented by commit [`3257368`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/3257368e97ef2f16b9b69f94d669f81f2f051058) with commit message "*Consider save when running task to be auto*", which I'm pretty sure is the culprit. Switching to AUTO (along with other implications) causes unsaved files to not participate in format-on-save for the save operation done by that build task (related source code can be found [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/df8db3a75a49b85c9636530a3557cdbc639f7bdc/src/vs/workbench/contrib/codeEditor/browser/saveParticipants.ts#L224)).

You have the opposite user want as the person who raised issue ticket #96904. What you should do is [raise a feature-request issue ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=feature_request.md) asking for an option to make build-task-saves participate in format-on-save.

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to it, or notify me in it with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.